# OpenCV 4.0 -- Waiting to capture from VideoCapture

Tags: c++, opencv, buffer, video-capture

### Problem

What I wanted to do is make a live video capture `VideoCapture cap` that only captures every set amount of time 'X', where X is typically anywhere between 500ms - 1s. If the difference between two captures `currentIMG` & `previousIMG` was high enough, it was supposed to do some kind of processing task and set the `previousIMG` to the one it just took so that it will be what it compares captures to from that point onward.

However, when attempting that, I noticed that **it didn't actually get what the camera was seeing at that moment on waking up**. To my knowledge, it just got whatever was "next in the buffer" for the `VideoCapture` object. This resulted in it just pausing before getting whatever is next in the buffer, rather than skipping all the things it saw in between those two time periods.

Is there a time efficient way to make sure I get whatever the "camera sees" on waking up and not just whatever was in the buffer next?

### Code used

```cpp
int main() {

    // open the camera and capture a image
    Mat currentIMG, previousIMG;
    VideoCapture cap;
    cap >> previousIMG;

    struct timespec ts = {ts.tv_sec = 1, ts.tv_nsec = 0};
    for (;;) {
        
        // wait & then capture an image for 'currentIMG'
        nanosleep(&ts, NULL);
        cap >> currentIMG;

        // check if the difference between the previous
        // and current images (in terms of decimal percentage)
        // exceeds the threshold 
        if (PSNR(currentIMG, previousIMG) > 0.20) {
    
            // Some kind of task that takes a bit to complete
            imwrite("capturedIMG.png", currentIMG);
            previousIMG = currentIMG.clone();
        }
    }

    // Exit
    return 0;
}
```

### What I tried so far

1. **Setting the buffer size with `cap.set(cv::CAP_PROP_BUFFERSIZE, 1)`**

I've tried setting the buffer size of `cap` to `1`, so I could limit the amount of images inside of the buffer. However, despite getting a `1` back when printing that call and it seeming like it's supported, it doesn't actually do anything to solve the issue.

2. **Threaded `grab()` loop**

I've tried using a series of `grab()`s in another thread with the main thread using a `retreive()` as per other stack overflow suggestions, and unfortunately it doesn't seem to work either. Sometimes it acts as if the spun off thread takes *everything* in the buffer such that the main thread has to wait to get something from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to start a thread that grabs AND retrieves (or simply reads) the frames, and nothing else is allowed to read from the camera or access the VideoCapture object.

that thread stores the latest frame somewhere, so the rest of your program can get that frame whenever it needs to.

use synchronization primitives such as "condition variables" to signal consumers of a fresh frame, so they can wait for the next fresh frame instead of potentially getting the same frame twice. here's a [python recipe for the problem](https://gist.github.com/crackwitz/15c3910f243a42dcd9d4a40fcdb24e40), probably translatable into C++ with little effort.

Comment: Isn't there a way to make it only have the "newest" frame? Or is having an extra thread at all times my only option?

Comment: the usual "hack" to force no stale frames is to set buffer to a low value (not sure what it means, frames, bytes, ...) but that often doesn't work. the only way I know is to run an extra thread for this. OpenCV APIs are not made for this, unfortunately. I think they'd accept a pull request but they won't implement it themselves.

Comment: I grant you, industrial cameras probably have APIs that actually expose the picture exactly when you call `grab()` (implied in `read`), not in fixed intervals, so those would not have that problem. you could play around with `apiPreference`, see if something spares you from going to the trouble. I wouldn't bet on it. extra thread for reading is the surest way to solve this.

Comment: here's a little recipe (in python) I once wrote up for this kind of question. I think you can translate that with little effort into C++. https://gist.github.com/crackwitz/15c3910f243a42dcd9d4a40fcdb24e40